# Avoid re-rendering not possible - but docs say should be no need of shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: redux, react-redux

The redux docs state that when using redux with react, so using the `connect` from the `react-redux` package. That there should be no need for `shouldComponentUpdate` - http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

> Redux library's connect() function, which provides many useful optimizations to prevent unnecessary re-renders. (One result of this is that you shouldn't have to worry about the React performance suggestion of implementing shouldComponentUpdate yourself.)

However my component is unnecesarily updated because I am returing a new array every time even though the contents of the array is the same. Here is my code:

```
const AssetManagerSmart = connect(
    function(state) {
        const { assets } = state;
        return {
            assetIds: assets.map( asset => asset.id )
        }
    }
)
```

See this `assetIds`, it is a map of an array from the redux state. This is causing my component to re-render. To simplify the code above, we can imagine `assetIds` is assigned to a new shallowly equal array everytime, like this:

```
const AssetManagerSmart = connect(
    function(state) {
        const { assets } = state;
        return {
            assetIds: ['hi']
        }
    }
)
```

How come the docs say I should not need `shouldComponentUpdate` when I am encountering the above? The above I see everyone doing, even in the "usage with react" section on official redux docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connect is in the default `pure` mode it performs [several checks](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#optimizing-connect-when-optionspure-is-true) that aim to avoid invoking `mapStateToProps`, and if it was invoked, prevent rerender of the wrapped component if nothing changed.

To check if it should run `mapStateToProps` (and `mergeProps`) connects makes 2 equality checks:

- `areStatesEqual` - checks if the entire state changed using strict equality. Whenever the store changes this will return `false`. However, you can override it, to check if a certain piece of the store changed. In your case you might want to check if `assets` have changed:

  ```
  (next, prev) => prev.assets === next.assets
  ```
- `areOwnPropsEqual` - makes a shallow equality checks to see if the props supplied to the component returned from connect have changed. Since you don't use props, you can theoretically override this to always return `true`, however this will prevent rerenders on prop changes completely.

If `mapStateToProps` is invoked 2 checks are performed to see if it should rerender the wrapped component:

- `areStatePropsEqual` - shallow equality between the current and previous results of `mapStateToProps`. This will check if prev `{ assetIds: [] }` equals `{ assetIds: [] }`, and since the `assetsIds` array changed will return `false`.
- `areMergedPropsEqual` - shallow equality between the current and previous results of `mergeProps` - the combined `ownProps`, `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`.

So if your state changes or your props change, `mapStateToProps` will be called, and the `assetIds` will recalculate. You can override the the `areStatesEqual` and `areOwnPropsEqual` to whitelist only specific changes that should invoke `mapStateToProps`.

The result of `mapStateToProps` will be shallow checked vs. the previous result. You can override the check to actually see if the items in the `assetIds` have changed, but that may be expensive, and you would also need to the same in `areMergedPropsEqual`. An easier options is to use a memoized selector.

**Memoized Selectors**

A selector can take a piece of the store, and compute derived data. A [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) selector will return the same result (without performing the computation) as long as the relevant part of the state did not change. Since the result is the same array (not a new array with similar values), this will pass the `areStatePropsEqual` and `areMergedPropsEqual` checks (unless something else changed).

[Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a library that helps you in creating memoized selectors.

This is how you can create a memoized selector for the assets' ids (not tested):

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getAssets = ({ assets }) => assets; /** simple not memoized selector **/

const getAssetIds = createSelector( /** memoized selector **/
    getAssets,
    (assets) => assets.map(asset => asset.id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you @OriDrori but I don't understand why the redux docs are saying that there is no need for shouldComponentUpdate. Using memoization is going to increase the space complexity. A simple shallowCompare would do the trick no? Also why did you memoize `getAssets`, as the `assets` field in the redux store will only change when  something changes (if reducers were done properly), so that is a simple reference check, does `connect` not even do this simple reference check?

Comment: In the `options` section here - https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments - it explains that if `pure` is `true` it does shallow comparing and reference equalities, so memoizing `getAssets` is not necessary right?

Comment: I've updated the answer. See if it gives you the info you need. `getAssets` is not memoized (it just returns a reference to the state).

Comment: That is amazingly helpful, thank you very very much!!

Comment: I had to +1 that comment too, the few points I could give you do not do justice to the understanding you have improved for me sir. :)

Comment: I've gained more understanding of the subject when composing the answer, and that is prize enough :)

Comment: You are too kind sir!